# JS How to match a value from one DOM element with id of other DOM element

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, if-statement, dom

```
function newFunction(element){
        var period  = document.getElementById('period').value;
        for(var l = 0; l < period; l++){
            var valueEnteredID = document.getElementById('time' +l);
            var valueEnteredCLASS = document.getElementsByClassName('time' +l);
            if(valueEnteredID == valueEnteredCLASS){
                var valueEntered = element.value;
                var timeEntered = document.getElementById(???)
            };
        };
    };
```

So I have this function, the problem is timeEntered. It is in a for loop and I want to get all ids in that loop, and match them with valueEntered. If we have a match I want to alert the value of the input timeEntered.

here is a screenshot of it:

[image]

Comment: Show us your HTML.

Comment: could you add some labels to your html so that when you talking about something we can make the logical assumption as which text-box you are talking about. never mind we can see id in html... supplied maybe a clearer explanation of what you wanting

Comment: in the HTML, I only have form, input and submit mostly is done with DOM elements. If you want here is a link to the code https://files.fm/u/vhsss88t#_

Comment: so basically you want the parent container of the changed element, and loop through it so that you can get all the input values...?

Comment: #tag id's should never be repeated on a single page....

Comment: You need to change your entire approach to this. My first suggestion would be to learn how to use CSS as opposed to inline styles. Next, learn about classes and how you can grab elements using selectors. You do *not* need to assign a uniquely composed `id` to each element.